# I am not able to get complete call stack which can direct me to source code

Tags: c++, c, windbg, dump, minidump

I am beginner in WinDbg, I have to analyze a user mode dump in WinDbg.

I have set up environment variables for downloading Microsoft symbols  as `srv*c:\Symbols\cache*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` and symbols related to the Dump: "C:\symbols\RP\4359" but when I run `!heap -p -a <address>` I am not getting call stack which can direct me towards the code.

Call stack which will direct me to source code.

Comment: "[Before you can use any !heap -p extension command, the page heap must be enabled for your target process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-heap)." Was page heap enabled?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need to enable page heap in GFlags:

[image: GFlags +HPA Page Heap]

Equivalent command line: `gflags /i my.exe +hpa`.

To check if it was enabled, use `!gflag` in WinDbg and it needs to show `hpa` in its output. To enable it just for one debugging session, use `!gflag +hpa` (not sure if this works only at the initial breakpoint, it'll certainly not affect allocations which have already happened).